# Javascript - Exception/Error data type?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, exception

```
try {
  example.example = example;
}  catch (err) {
  TraceError.sysout("Error test!", err);
}
```

In this above code segment, I am forcing an error since example is not defined. I am learning javascript currently and was wondering if in javascript what type err would be. Is there an Error object or an Exception object in this language, and is there a way to get information about that err object so that I can print a detailed message in my .sysout method?

Comment: you can check adding `alert` or `console` and check in Firebug of Browser or add `breakpoint` in Browser

Comment: when I do console.log(typeof(err)), I just see 'object'

Comment: console.log(err). Does that return object?

Comment: Yes it returns object. I had figured any exception that was caught in a try/catch statement would be a specific type not just object.

Comment: The goal is have some verification that the err object is a error/exception type before doing any logging

Comment: try doing a for in loop on the object to display it's properties.

Comment: basically, if you ever want to know if something is an object or otherwise, you can simply open your debugger (F12) and simply look at the code. As you just found out, it is quite easy to figure out if `err` is an object or not.

Comment: I know that err is an object because it was an exception that was caught. My question was is in javascript is there an exception or error data type? I mean is there methods I can call on this err object so I can get more information about the error? i.e (made up)

err.methodItCameFrom
err.errorMessage

Comment: Yes, that information can be found through the debugger. I would also recommend taking a read through the article below. There's' a nice bit about how to check the type of error the `err` would throw. Interesting question though. I learned a couple things from the article I didn't know.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

Answer (score 3):

use console.log or console.dir

```
 try {
     example.example = example;
  }  catch (err) {
    console.dir(err);
    console.log("Error Message!", err.message);
    console.log("Stack Trace" , err.stack);
 }
```

In this case if you check out your console you will notice that the error type is "**ReferenceError**".

Hence, every exception has a type.

Try to do this and you'll get the following:

```
 var x = undefined;
 x.myproperty= 0
 TypeError: Cannot set property 'myproperty' of undefined

 myfaultySyntax'
 SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

And so on! hopes this helps and gives you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript does have a standard built in Error object which can be used for creating and logging errors.

Instances to Error objects are thrown when run-time errors occur (JavaScript provides a few built in standard error types). You can also use the error object as a base objects for 'user-defined exceptions'.

You can refer the following link for the complete documentation:

'https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error'

Hope the answer helps.

(Also by looking at the code in the try block in the question, I assumed that you are familiar with object oriented programming.)